# How to upload the same file using Angular?

Tags: angular

I use the following code to upload a file in Angular:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="file">Choose File</label>
 <input type="file"
       id="file"
       (change)="uploadRenewals($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
fileToUpload: File = null;

uploadRenewals(files: FileList) {
  console.log('Uploading starts...', files);
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
  formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);
  this._docService.uploadRenewals(formData)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((response: RenewalsResponse) => {
    console.log('Response is', response);
   }, (error) => {console.log(error);});
```

**Service**

```
uploadRenewals(formData: FormData) {
 return this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/docs/uploadRenewals', formData, { responseType: 'json' })
 .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

The thing here is that it works when I upload different file each time, but when I try to upload the same file nothing is triggered and the `uploadRenewals()` function is never called.

Also I noticed that when I open the window `(change)="uploadRenewals($event.target.files)` the third time (after I chose the same file the 2nd time and nothing happened) and close it without selecting any file, the `uploadRenewals()` is called and in `console` is showed the below error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Any idea what is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EXPLANATION :

What you need is to clear the input file Element after each upload and for the second problem if you close the dialog and the event **(change)** fired with an empty event then when it comes to this line:

```
formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);
```

*this.fileToUpload is empty.*

### SOLUTION :

***TS :***

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('fileInput', {
    static: false
}) fileInput: ElementRef;
fileToUpload: File = null;

uploadRenewals(files: FileList) {
    console.log('Uploading starts...', files);
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    if (this.fileToUpload) { // this condition to avoid your the error that you mentioned
        formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);
        this._docService.uploadRenewals(formData)
            .pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe((response: RenewalsResponse) => {
                console.log('Response is', response);
                this.fileInput.nativeElement.value = null; //this clears the input file to let the event (change) fire again so you can upload the same file again
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

***HTML :***

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="file">Choose File</label>
 <input #fileInput type="file"
       id="file"
       (change)="uploadRenewals($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked, but the only thing that I think you should change is `@ViewChild('fileInput', {static: false}) fileInput: ElementRef;`! Thanks again :)